# Cumulative Line Numbers in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

Is there a way to add cumulative line numbers (like in a LaTeX file) to a Microsoft Word document? You can add line numbers to a page easily, but the numbering resets on the following page. So if page 1 has 25 lines, I want the fist line on the second page to start with #26, page 3 with #52, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the bottom of the Layout tab in Page Setup (above the OK button), you'll see a Line Numbers button... click that to bring up the Line Numbers dialog, and select Continuous (option at bottom of dialog).
[image]